# Hashmap con una clave y un objeto dentro con dos atributos

Tags: objeto, hashmap

Necesito crear un hashmap con una clave y un objeto en su interior que contenga dos atributos para introducir varios registros de una query de bbdd que me devuelve.

¿como lo puedo crear para luego poder acceder al objeto perteneciente a esa clave del hashmap?

si tenéis un ejemplo, genial.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Revisa el apartado [ask] para crear una publicación que sea de mayor interés y así encontrar una respuesta a tu pregunta. Comparte lo que has intentado o dónde te has atascado, las preguntas sin código que no muestran ningún intento terminan cerradas. También puedes hacer el [tour] y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un `HashMap` con tu objeto, o si quieres que sea dinámico puede usar la clase `Object` y usar un casteo a la hora de obtener el objeto. Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo que te serviría para guardar cualquier tipo de objeto en el `HashMap`:

```
Map<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Prueba objPrueba = new Prueba("field1", "field2");

hashMap.put("Object", objPrueba);

Prueba response = (Prueba) hashMap.get("Object");
```

Comment: No está bien visto responder las preguntas cuya finalidad sea "hacerles" las cosas, sino han intentado nada, no se responde nada.